# android.hardware.Camera fails to open every second time

Tags: android, c++, camera, unreal-engine4

#### Problem background

I am developing a VR Project on Unreal Engine 4, and the project requires the usage of Android's native camera. Since there are no built-in functions in UE4 to iteract with Android's native methods, I customized [this plugin](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?117571-Plugin-Android-Camera) under my need.

The original plugin uses the JNI interface to iteract with C++ code. It calls `camera.open()` and `camera.startPreview()` on UE4's `EventBeginPlay`, and calls `camera.stopPreview()` and `camera.Release()` on UE4's `EventEndPlay`. Since it is a [known issue](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/243769/android-mobile-event-end-play-problem.html) that `EventEndPlay` never fires up on Android platform, I decided to manipulate the camera in `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods. Here is the code:

```
<gameActivityClassAdditions>
<insert>
  /* Unrelevant code goes here */
    ...
    ...
  /* End of unrelevant code */

  public void AndroidThunkJava_startCamera()
  {                        
    surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(10);
    surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(preferredWidth, preferredHeight);

    if (camera == null){
      try {
        camera = Camera.open();
      } catch (RuntimeException exc) {
        return;
      }
    }               

    try {
      camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
    } catch (IOException t) {
      return;
    }

    Parameters cameraParam = camera.getParameters();

    cameraParam.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
    cameraParam.setPreviewSize(preferredWidth, preferredHeight);
    cameraParam.setPreviewFpsRange(preferredFPS, preferredFPS);
    cameraParam.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
    if (cameraParam.isVideoStabilizationSupported()) {
      cameraParam.setVideoStabilization(false);
    }
    if (cameraParam.isAutoWhiteBalanceLockSupported()) {
      cameraParam.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(false);
    }

    camera.setParameters(cameraParam);

    camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        int Height = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
        int Width = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;

        // calling C++ function via JNI interface
        processFrameData(Width, Height, data);
      }
    });

    camera.startPreview();
  }

  public void AndroidThunkJava_stopCamera()
  {
    if (camera != null)
    {
      camera.stopPreview();
      camera.release();
      camera = null;
    }
  }
</insert>
</gameActivityClassAdditions>

<gameActivityOnPauseAdditions>
<insert>
  AndroidThunkJava_stopCamera();
</insert>
</gameActivityOnPauseAdditions>

<gameActivityOnResumeAdditions>
<insert>  
  AndroidThunkJava_startCamera();
</insert>
</gameActivityOnResumeAdditions>
```

#### The problem

The camera works fine every second time. That means:

I open the app, camera is working. I pushed the home button (which triggers `onPause()` method), then switch back to the app (triggers `onResume()` method). Pushed the home button again, and then switched back - camera works.  And so on, the camera works every second time.

Anybody have any idea about this issue? Is that connected to the fact that `android.hardware.Camera` is deprecated? I'm using API version 19, so it is not possible to use newer `android.hardware.camera2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my onStop and onResume methods. I'm not using onPause. And it works perfectly:

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mCamera == null) {
            restartPreview();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        // stop the preview
        if (mCamera != null) {
            stopCameraPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        super.onStop();
    }

 private void restartPreview() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            stopCameraPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }



            getCamera(mCameraID);
            startCameraPreview();
        }

private void startCameraPreview() {


        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            setSafeToTakePhoto(true);
            setCameraFocusReady(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("st", "Can't start camera preview due to IOException " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 private void stopCameraPreview() {
        setSafeToTakePhoto(false);
        setCameraFocusReady(false);

        // Nulls out callbacks, stops face detection
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mPreviewView.setCamera(null);
    }
```

maybe some implementations not equals yours but i think it is help you.